# Boto3 SQS Intermittent AccessDenied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sqs, boto3

I have five Docker containers with identical Python codebases that concurrently pull items from an SQS queue and process them. However, I am randomly receiving crashes with the following exception on the fifth container (and occasionally the fourth):

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when
>   calling the ReceiveMessage operation: Access to the resource
>   https://queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.

I have confirmed that they all share identical AWS permissions, and the other containers have had zero crashes in the past week (and have been processing without issue)

To me this indicates the possibility that there is a maximum number of concurrent polling connections permitted on SQS but I haven't found any indication that this is true.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14073

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same issue. Why would it always be the same container and why only SQS (I'm not receiving any errors to other APIs I'm hitting).